# git command fails with exit code 128 warning: url contains a newline in its username component then fatal: credential url cannot be parsed

Tags: git, github, gcloud

After updating my GitHub personal access token `GH_TOKEN` env var on my CI/CD pipeline, I started seeing the error:

```
Command failed with exit code 128:
git ls-remote --heads https://[secure]@github.com/darthwalsh/FireSocket.git

stderr:
warning: url contains a newline in its username component: https://[secure]@github.com/darthwalsh/FireSocket.git/
fatal: credential url cannot be parsed: https://[secure]@github.com/darthwalsh/FireSocket.git/
```

**Why does git fail with this error?**

---

For completeness

- I put the PAT into `plain.txt`
- ran `gcloud kms encrypt --plaintext-file plain.txt --ciphertext-file crypt`
- copied the output of `< crypt base64`
- pasted the base64 output into `cloudbuild.yaml`
- the `semantic-release` module failed at `/workspace/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/git.js:66:11`

Comment: what's the output of this `cloud-build-local --config=cloudbuild.yaml --dryrun=true .` ?

Comment: @chintanthakar https://pastebin.com/KbyAeB6q I don't see anything interesting -- the output literally has `--env GH_TOKEN=<REDACTED>`. I think you should be able to recreate it (but you might need to create your own KMS keyring).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the bytes of the PAT contains a literal `\n`, which git is warning is probably wrong.

Make sure to use `-n` arg when running `$  echo -n ghp_TOKENTOKEN > plain.txt` to remove the trailing newline from the data being encrypted.